# Python Tornado - Changing unrealistic example to realistic example

Tags: python, tornado

```
import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')

class PoemPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        noun1 = self.get_argument('noun1')
        noun2 = self.get_argument('noun2')
        verb = self.get_argument('verb')
        noun3 = self.get_argument('noun3')
        self.render('poem.html', roads=noun1, wood=noun2, made=verb,difference=noun3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers=[(r'/', IndexHandler), (r'/poem', PoemPageHandler)],
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
    )
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

This sample code is from the book 'Introduction to Tornado'. This example code in a single file is quite easy to understand but it's not really practical because it's creating multiple classes in a single file.

What I want to do is - I'd like to create individual module(?) files that handles specific pages and its actions. For example, I'd like to rewrite the codes in three different files.

1. main.py - it has __ main __ stuff and calls a proper Handler as needed
2. IndexHandler.py
3. PoemHandler.py

Since I'm new to this Python Tornado Framework, I'm not quite sure what the best way to rewrite & refactor the whole codes. Would someone please show me a better way of separating py files to maintain classes easily?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this repo](https://github.com/st4lk/acl_webapp). It contains an example of tornado project.

It takes an idea from django. It splitted into apps and apps are splittend into models, handlers, forms, etc.

```
acl_webapp  # <-- the project
    +-- base      # <-- app (contains base forms, models, handlers)
    +-- accounts  # <-- app
    +-- logs
    +-- news      # <-- app
    |   +-- __init__.py
    |   +-- forms.py      # <-- contains forms
    |   +-- handlers.py   # <-- contains handlers
    |   +-- models.py     # <-- contains models
    +-- pages     # <-- app
    +-- static
    +-- templates
    +-- utils
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- app.py        # <-- tornado Application entry point
    +-- settings.py   # <-- project settings
    +-- urls.py       # <-- project urls
```

Comment: Yeessssssssssssss!!! This was what I looking for!! A well organized sample project!!  All the examples I was referring to were single file ones - easy for books to explain but hard to use in real life.  Thanks Stalk !